# Trying Update Record with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I updated the question code I am still having issues no errors but does not update the record. also need to figure how to write in record # updated successfully. I am stuck on this update page.

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
require_once("db_connect.php");
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $lanId = $_REQUEST['lanId'];
  $name= $_REQUEST['name'];
  $department = $_REQUEST['department'];
  $manager= $_REQUEST['manager'];
  $request = $_REQUEST['request'];
 $request_description = $_REQUEST['request_description'];
  $request_comments = $_REQUEST['request_comments'];
  $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
  $comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
  $compUser = $_REQUEST['compUser'];
  $compDt = $_REQUEST['compDt'];
  
  
  $sql =   "UPDATE requests SET " . 
    "lanId =  '" . $lanId . "', ".
    "name =  '" . $name . "', ".
    "department = '" . $department . "', ".
    "manager = '" . $manager. "', " .
    "request = '" . $request. "', " .
    "request_description = '" . $request_description. "', " .
    "request_comments = '" . $request_comments. "', " .
    "status = '" . $status. "', " .
    "comments = '" . $comments. "', " .
    "compUser = '" . $compUser. "', " .
    "compDt = '" . $compDt. "'  WHERE id = '" . $id .  "';";
    
    #echo($sql);
    
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error);
    
   print("Record " . $id .  " has been updated. .")


?>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=StatusPages/received.php>
<title>

</title>
</head>
<body background="images/background.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

update.php page

```
<?php
    include('db_connect.php');
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id= :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

}
.body{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: thin solid #666666;
}
</style>

</head>
<body class='body'>
<form action = "update_process.php" " method ="post" class="Form">


<p><input type ="hidden" name = "id" value="<?php print($id); ?>"</p>

<h2 align="center">Users request  Information</h2>
<table border='1' align="center">
<tr>    
    <td>LAN ID:</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['lanId']) ?>"name="lanId"></td>

    <td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['name']) ?>"name="name"></td>
</tr>

<tr>    
    <td>Department Location</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['department']) ?>"name="department"></td>

    <td>Manager</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['manager']) ?>"name="manager"></td>
</tr>


<tr>    
    <td>Request</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['request']) ?>"name="request"></td>

<td>Request Description</td>
<td><input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['request_description']) ?>"name="request_description"></td>

</tr>
</table>

<table border='1' align="center">
<br>
<h2 align='center'>Requested Comments</h2>
<tr>    

<td width='300'  height="40">
<input type="text" value ="<?php  print($row['request_comments'.'']) ?>"name="request_comments" size="50" style="height: 32px; width: 587px;" ></td>

</tr>

</table>


<h2 align="center">Complete or Update Requests Status</h2>

<table border='1' align="center" style="width: 595px">
<tr>    
    <td>Completed Date</td>
<td style="width: 303px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php echo date("Y-m-d",time())?>"name="compDt" style="width: 148px"></td>


</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>Status</td>
<td style="width: 303px"><select name ="status" style="width: 149px" >
<option value <?php if ($row['status']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Received">Received</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['status']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Completed">Completed</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['status']==3){ print('selected');}  ?> ="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['status']==4){ print('selected');}  ?> ="In_Progress">In_Progress</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['status']==5){ print('selected');}  ?> ="On_Hold">On_Hold</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Completed by</td>
<td style="width: 303px"><select name ="compUser" style="width: 149px" >
<option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="unasigned">Please Select....</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==1){ print('selected');}  ?> ="xgrh">xgrh</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="zeap">zeap</option>
<option value <?php if ($row['compUser']==2){ print('selected');}  ?> ="xjae">xjae</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>


</table>




<div align='center'>    
<br>Comments:<br>   
<textarea name="comments" Value = "<?php  print($row['request_comments']) ?>"  style="width: 593px; height: 100px"></textarea><br>
    <br><br>
<input type="submit" value= "Update Information">
<br>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

update_process.php page

```html
<?php
 include('db_connect.php');
 
   $action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
            if($action == "update"){ 
            try{    
            global $conn;
 $sql = 'UPDATE requests SET lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':lanId', $_POST['lanId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['$name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':department', $_POST['department'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':manager', $_POST['manager'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request', $_POST['request'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':request_description', $_POST['request_description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request_comments', $_POST['request_comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':compUser', $_POST['compUser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comDt', $_POST['comDt'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }   
}
  


?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and add error reporting to your PDO statement. Your query is way out of shape from a syntax point of view and error checking would have revealed that to you.

Comment: `$affected_rows->execute()` is most definitely not what you want here. You should be preparing a statement with `prepare()` and placeholders, then calling `execute()` on the statement.  The [PDO tutorial for MySQL developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Named_Placeholders) explains it well, and in context of the old `mysql_*()` functions if that is your background.

Comment: Try `$db->prepare` instead of `$db->exec` also add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: You don't have a named element called `action` and I don't know which form element you wish to check for. This for `$_POST['action']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is a mess.**

You should use HEREDOC for big queries like this.
Read more about HEREDOCs [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).
Furthermore getting the affected row count is done with rowCount ()
More on that [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

I don't think you understand how prepared statements work either.

I **highly** advice you read up some of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Lastly please read up on [what is wrong with $_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request).

Now for the monstrousity you've managed to produce...

```
<?php


$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "test";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $lanId = $_REQUEST['lanId'];
  $name= $_REQUEST['name'];
  $department = $_REQUEST['department'];
  $manager= $_REQUEST['manager'];
  $request = $_REQUEST['request'];
  $request_description = $_REQUEST['request_description'];
  $request_comments = $_REQUEST['request_comments'];
  $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
  $comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
  $compUser = $_REQUEST['compUser'];
  $compDt = $_REQUEST['compDt'];

$update =
<<<SQL

UPDATE requests
    SET lanID = ?,
        name = ?,
        department = ?,
        manager = ?,
        request = ?,
        request_description = ?,
        status = ?,
        comments = ?,
        compUser = ?,
        compDt = ?

        WHERE id = ?;

SQL;

$stmt = $db->prepare ($update);
$stmt->execute (array ($lanId, $name, $department, $manager, $request, $request_description,
                $status, $comments, $compUser, $compDt, $id));

echo $stmt->rowCount () . " rows were affected.";
echo "Record " . $id . " has been updated.";


?>
```

Comment: Thank you I was going to keep trying to figure it out and repost new code. I changed $_REQUEST to $_POST also I tried the code you had above but i get syntax error on line 25 $update = UPDATE requests SET lanID = ?,name = ?,department = ?,manager = ?,request= ?,request_description = ?,status = ?,comments = ?,compUser = ?,compDt = ?, WHERE id = ?;

Comment: @Donny I edited it and tested it, it should work now ;)

Comment: I am still getting a parse error on line 25 unexpected 'UPDATE'(T_STRING)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'requests' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on line 25 now requests is getting error

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcW8mMiIexc I found tutorials I am going to go through too

Comment: I updated the code still having issues wrote it in a different direction not sure if I am in the right path

Comment: not working seems to go to the page but not update the request no errors are shown

Answer (score 2):

This code is a disaster:

```
$affected_rows = $db->exec("UPDATE requests SET") . 
                                               ^^---terminating your query here
                "lanId =  '" . $lanId . "', ".
```

So you run a malformed query (`UPDATE requests SET`), which will either throw an exception of return boolean FALSE. You then concatenate a whole bunch of text (which would've been part of your query) onto that FALSE.

And even if this code was properly structured, you'd be WIDE OPEN to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).